# WCF Caching List Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, list

I am trying to cache a dynamic list retrieved from a SQL Server in WCF, the retrieving process is working fine so far, and I've tested it and there are no problems at all with it, the problem is when I try to cache this retrieved list, an error occurs that I am not able to find out the reason behind it.

Here is my method :

```
public List<ErrorEntities> GetALL()
{
            List<ErrorEntities> res = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Cache["GetALL"] == null)
            {
                SqlCommand com = Global.GetCommand("select * from [BlockingList]");
                com.Connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                res = Fill(reader);

                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add("GetALL", res, null, DateTime.Now.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15)), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

                com.Connection.Close();
                return res;
            }
            else
            {
                res = HttpRuntime.Cache["GetALL"] as List<ErrorEntities>;
                return res;
            }
}
```

I've tried to enable the caching on the web.config file by adding the following line of code but the problem wasn't solved as well:

```
<scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true"    enableCaching="true" />
```

and here is the error I get when I compile the solution:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> ```
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> ```
>
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more
> ```
>
> information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.
>
> ```
> Source Error: 
>
>
> Line 113:        
> Line 114:        public ServiceReference1.ErrorEntities[] GetALL() {
> Line 115:            return base.Channel.GetALL();
> Line 116:        }
> Line 117:
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that code shown in question is called inside WCF method.

WCF works in its own context and `HttpContext.Current` should not be used there.

Microsoft added new cache that has no `System.Web` dependency in .NET 4.0.

`MemoryCache` should work fine in WCF.

Try to use this code for getting cache object:

```
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

I would also recommend to use `using` or `try-finally` blocks for disposable resources (`Connection` in code sample)